# Did Gandalf fly on an eagle back to Middle-earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf

How was Gandalf able to return to Middle-earth and get to Fangorn that fast? The most logical explanation is that he either took an eagle of Manwe, or travelled, like, "spiritually" similar to how he travelled *from* Celebdil.

By ship it would take multiple weeks to go from Valinor to Mithlond. From there on even if he rode all the way on Shadowfax it would take him days, if not weeks. He would first have to go back to Zirakzigil to take his sword Glamdring (but not his staff as he got a new one, and his former one is probably destroyed) and then head on to the Fangorn woods. In that timeframe that's only accomplishable if he rode all the way from Valinor on a Great Eagle, unless he was travelling spiritually and his body was renewed still there on the summit before or while Gandalf reentered his body.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer to this question is "No".

Gandalf was resurrected where he died, on Zirakzigil amid the destruction of the fight with the balrog:

> ...naked I lay upon the mountain-top. The tower behind was crumbled
> into dust, the window gone; the ruined stair was choked with burned
> and broken stone. I was alone, forgotten, without escape upon the hard
> horn of the world

Presumably he returned to life there by the reanimation of his old body. This is just as well, or the difficulties of recovering his sword and ring would have been formidable. Having been restored to life, the text in the Two Towers tells us that Gwaihir the eagle brought him to Lórien where his healing was completed.

So eagle transport *was* involved, but only from Moria to Lórien. From there it is a comparatively short distance to Fangorn.

On the subject of how long all this took, "The Tale of Years" puts the death of the balrog (and Gandalf passing away) on January the 25th. Gandalf returned to life on February the 14th, and is delivered to Lórien by eagle on the 17th of February (the day after the fellowship left). Aragorn, Legolas and Gimli then met him in Fangorn on March the 1st, but he had clearly arrived a few days earlier, discussing things with Treebeard.

Comment: So he flew spiritually from Valinor back to Zirakzigil into his body? How long has he been in Valinor, as a matter of fact?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a direct intervention by Eru. How long it took is hard to say, he "strayed out of thought and time"

Comment: @AragornElessar - The ainur were capable of teleporting, definitely when not physically embodied.

Comment: @ibid Right maybe Gandalf was teleported (he's not an Ainu himself but he may have been teleported to Celebdil). One may have opened an Einstein Rosen Bridge for him.

Comment: @AragornElessar - Gandalf is an Ainu. The maiar are all ainur.

Comment: @ibid Gandalf is of the Istari, five wizards who came to Middle-earth in the third age. Was he created before the Sun?

Comment: @AragornElessar - The Istari were all maiar, and had been hanging out in Valinor prior to their journey to Middle-earth. You can read more about them in The Silmarillion, Unfinished Tales, The Peoples of Middle-earth, and The Nature of Middle-earth.

Comment: @ibid So why did they spend all the millenia in Valinor instead of going to help Middle-earth in the 1st and/or 2nd age?

Comment: Good question. If it hasn't been asked, you should ask it.

Comment: @MattGutting I think someone should ask who is more knowledgeable on the background story of the Istari. I didn't even know they'd be hanging out in Aman from before the First Age.

Comment: In brief, the consequences of their hands-on intervention in Beleriand convinced the Valar to be more hands-off throughout the Second Age. Even at the end, when Ar-Pharazon landed in Aman, they simply stepped aside to let Eru handle it. One imagines Eru having a little heart-to-heart chat with Manwë about an approach somewhere between "stomp Sauron" and "leave the mortals to their own devices", leading to sending the Istari as advisors, not actors.

Answer (score 3):

Your misunderstanding here is that he traveled from Valinor. He didn't: he "strayed out of (thought and) time". Valinor may be outside hitter realms, but it is still in Arda, ie in time. But Gandalf left time itself, so was no longer in Arda.

Comment: He was "sent back until his task is fulfilled". Back from where? If the War of the Ring is won and Sauron defeated Gandalf would sail to Valinor. But I agree that surroundings of Gandalf's fate on Zirakzigil are confusing and unclear.

Comment: @AragornElessar - Gandalf passed "out of thought and time." Where is that? Not Valinor. Tolkien wrote in letter 156, regarding what happened to him: "He was sent by a mere prudent plan of the angelic Valar or governors; but Authority had taken up this plan and enlarged it, at the moment of its failure. “Naked I was sent back – for a brief time, until my task is done”. Sent back by whom, and whence? Not by the “gods” whose business is only with this embodied world and its time; for he passed “out of thought and time”." Sent back to Zirakzigil. For "Authority" read the Creator God, Eru Ilúvatar.